# python-social-auth - how could I disconnect in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I'm using `a` tag with href like `/disconnect/backend/` and then it shows me an empty page. I've tried `{% url %}` template tag like:

```
{% url 'social:disconnect' 'twitter' %}
```

And it's still create same url as I've used in the tag. How could I disconnect account? Or maybe there are also a way to get only one account associated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer is very simple. You should use POST request. I've done it like those:

```
<form action="{% url 'social:disconnect' 'twitter' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">
        Disconnect
    </button>
</form>
```